# How to undo update if Upsert is update and do delete if Upsert is insert with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to add function for create data into 2 tables in my expressJs apps using Sequelize.

Controller:

```
Campaign.upsert({
    institution_id : institution_id,
    description : campaign_about
}).then(value => {
    InstitutionDetail.create({
        institution_id : institution_id,
        support_description : support_description,
        img_homepage : img_homepage
    }).then(value1 => {
        var campaign = {};
        var obj = {campaign};

        obj.campaign = value;
        obj.institution_detail = support_description;
        obj.institution_img_home = img_homepage;

        res.json({
            'data': obj
        })
    }).catch(reason => {
        if(value == true){
            //if campaign created
            Campaign.destroy({force: true, where:{institution_id:institution_id}});
        } else {
            //if campaign updated
            //how to undo the updated, so I can have the previous data back
            Campaign.destroy({where:{institution_id:institution_id}});
        }
        News.destroy({where:{id:value2.id}});
        Testimony.destroy({where:{id:value1.id}});
        responseUtil.fail(res, reason)
    })
}).catch(reason => responseUtil.fail(res, reason))
```

If the `create` in *InstitutionDetail* is failed, I want to destroy the created data of *Campaign*, or get the previous data back if the *Campaign* do `update`.

I've successfully delete the *Campaign* data using `destroy` inside the catch if the *Campaign* do `create`, but I don't know what to do if the *Campaign* do `update`.

I've tried using `paranoid` in the **model**:

```
timestamps: true,
paranoid: true
```

and add column `deletedAt` in model.

But it only set the `deletedAt` as current time, didn't do get data back if *Campaign* do `update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As per the **[doc](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-upsert)** :
>
> Returns a boolean indicating whether the row was created or updated.
>   For MySQL/MariaDB, it returns true when inserted and false when
>   updated. For Postgres/MSSQL with (options.returning=true), it returns
>   record and created boolean with signature .

**So try out :**

```
Campaign.upsert({
    institution_id : institution_id,
    description : campaign_about
}).then(value => {
    console.log(value); // <--- This should return true/false
});


Campaign.upsert({
    institution_id : institution_id,
    description : campaign_about
},{ returning : true }) // <----- with (options.returning=true)
.then(value => {
    console.log(value); // <--- This will return model + created : true/false
});
```

Comment: Yes you're right, but how to handle(destroy/get data back) the inserted/updated campaign if the `InstitutionDetail.create` fail

Comment: Based on that result you can perform the specific operation, as with `{ returning : true }` you will also get return data. @Blackjack